# windows command window (cmd) suddenly closed file , previous commands

Tags: windows, cmd, command

Yesterday I worked with some cmd files in windows, some how I could not able to open that on Today. is there any chance I can view history in command window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends. If the command prompt is the same instance as yesterday you can use the `up arrow key` to view previous commands.

If the window has been closed commands are lost. In future you could run, 
`doskey /HISTORY > somecommand.log`, before closing command prompt to save all commands used to a file for reference the next time you come to use it.

Comment: I have closed the command window. Is there any chance I can retrieve from log files?

Comment: No, the history has gone.

Comment: nope there are no logs created, you've lost the history, in future the command mentioned above would allow you to dump the command history to a file.